# Error on backup restore after convert to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, rake, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am in the process of migrating a Gitlab server to the Omnibus version, using the guide on: http://theterminallife.com/migrating-gitlab-to-gitlab-omnibus/

Everything works up to the point of the rake script on backup restore where I get several syntax errors on backticks.

```
@GitLabVM:~$ sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1452260428
Unpacking backup ... done
Restoring database ...
Restoring PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production ... ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `abuse_reports`;
                             ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `abuse_reports` (
                     ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: LOCK TABLES `abuse_reports` WRITE;
                    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNLOCK"
LINE 1: UNLOCK TABLES;
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `application_settings`;
                             ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `application_settings` (
                     ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: LOCK TABLES `application_settings` WRITE;
                    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO `application_settings` VALUES (1,10,1,1,1,NULL,'...
                    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNLOCK"
LINE 1: UNLOCK TABLES;
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `audit_events`;
```

I have checked the sql file, and it does not have the backticks that I receive errors on.

```
-- Converted by db_converter
START TRANSACTION;
SET standard_conforming_strings=off;
SET escape_string_warning=off;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "abuse_reports";
CREATE TABLE "abuse_reports" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL,
    "reporter_id" integer DEFAULT NULL,
    "user_id" integer DEFAULT NULL,
    "message" text ,
    "created_at" timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "application_settings";
CREATE TABLE "application_settings" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL,
    "default_projects_limit" integer DEFAULT NULL,
    "signup_enabled" int4 DEFAULT NULL,
    "signin_enabled" int4 DEFAULT NULL,
    "gravatar_enabled" int4 DEFAULT NULL,
.....
.....
```

There is a relevant bug report in Gitlab, but it has been deprecated and I cannot seem to find where this bug occurs. I would greatly appreciate any help in tracking this down. Thank you.

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/2437/files

Comment: Have you ever found the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when the dump was created from a MySQL database and during the restore process Postgress db gets these syntax errors

You can create a separate database dump with PostgreSQL compatibility and simply follow these steps.

```
sudo -u git -H mysqldump --compatible=postgresql--default-character-set=utf8 -r gitlabhq_production.mysql -u root gitlabhq_production -p

# Clone the database converter
sudo -u git -H git clone https://github.com/gitlabhq/mysql-postgresql-converter.git -b gitlab

# Convert gitlabhq_production.mysql
sudo -u git -H mkdir db
sudo -u git -H python mysql-postgresql-converter/db_converter.py gitlabhq_production.mysql db/database.sql
sudo -u git -H ed -s db/database.sql < mysql-postgresql-converter/move_drop_indexes.ed

# Compress database backup
# Warning: If you have Gitlab 7.12.0 or older skip this step and import the database.sql directly into the backup with:
# sudo -u git -H tar rf TIMESTAMP_gitlab_backup.tar db/database.sql
# The compressed databasedump is not supported at 7.12.0 and older.
sudo -u git -H gzip db/database.sql

# Replace the MySQL dump in TIMESTAMP_gitlab_backup.tar.

# Warning: if you forget to replace TIMESTAMP below, tar will create a new file
# 'TIMESTAMP_gitlab_backup.tar' without giving an error.

sudo -u git -H tar rf TIMESTAMP_gitlab_backup.tar db/database.sql.gz

# Done! TIMESTAMP_gitlab_backup.tar can now be restored into a Postgres GitLab
# installation.
# See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md for more information about backups.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/mysql_to_postgresql.html#converting-a-gitlab-backup-file-from-mysql-to-postgres
```

Refer: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/mysql_to_postgresql.html#converting-a-gitlab-backup-file-from-mysql-to-postgres